# Content projection in dynamic Angular components

Tags: angular

Is there a way to use content projection in dynamically loaded & created Angular 2 components? 
By dynamic loading & creation i mean components aren't known at compilation time, they will be loaded & compiled & instantiated in run time.

Answer (score 1):

You pass them as `projectableNodes` to `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html#!#createComponent-anchor

Comment: Thanks, but the usage of `projectableNodes` param is not clear. I found another stackoverflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106480/what-are-projectable-nodes-in-angular2/40323785#40323785), and it shows how you can insert programatically created DOM nodes to slots. Is this the only way to insert content? Can it be processed somehow from template file?

Comment: I guess you can use https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html#!#createEmbeddedView-anchorand pass the `rootNodes` from the returned https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EmbeddedViewRef-class.html