# angular dynamic component with nested components

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am building an app that is basically a e-book.  Each page has the same outer formatting with unique content which is defined using HTML and custom components.

The outer page is defined as:

```
<header></header>
  <outerborder>
    <page-content></page-content>
  </outerborder>
<footer><footer>
```

`page-content` has the template of

```
<div>
  <p class="title">{{title}}</p>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <p class="pageno">{{pageno}}</p
</div>
```

one of the `page-content` elements is then defined as

```
<page-content title="title1" pageno="6">
  <p>introduction</p>
  <custom-comp1>more text</custom-comp1>
  <custom-comp2>and more text</custom-comp2>
  <button>button text</button>
</page-content>
```

I have been following the guide at https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader and I want to use this guide to load page-content dynamically.

How can the `page-content` component be defined such that the inner contents are mapped into the `ng-content` element?  Should `ng-template` be used instead?

Has any one done anything similar where all the page-content elements are stored in the assets directory and loaded at dynamically?

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the content as `projectableNodes` should do that

```ts
let content = document.createElement('div');
content.innerHTML = `
  <p>introduction</p>
  <custom-comp1>more text</custom-comp1>
  <custom-comp2>and more text</custom-comp2>
  <button>button text</button>
`;

let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory, {projectableNodes: [content]});
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40323785/217408

Comment: This also could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284026/creating-a-angular2-component-with-ng-content-dynamically/44289996#44289996

Comment: In the angular example at  https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader, the add components are defined using: `new AdItem(HeroProfileComponent, {name: 'Bombasto', bio: 'Brave as they come'})`.  How can I define my `<page-content>` to use this model?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. There is no `new AdItem(...)` in the linked page.

Comment: Gunter, thank you so much for looking at this.  They don't have the full source on the page, its in the .zip download.  This is an equivalent plunker https://embed.plnkr.co/ZM2wSc/.  In the `loadComponent` function, values are assigned to the the various components.  I'm not sure how to define my `<page-content>` class so I can assign values to a property that gets into the  `<ng-content>` in the template.  Thanks again.